# C++ code not finding 10001th prime

Tags: c++

I wrote this code for project euler problem #7(Find the 10001st prime number) but it isn't working and is throwing out all sorts of obviously wrong answers(such as even numbers)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>  
using namespace std;

int main()
{
long long numprime = 1;
long long counter = 3;
long long arrofprimes[10001];
for(int i = 0; i < 10001; i++)
{
    arrofprimes[i] = 2;
}
while(true)
{
    if(numprime == 10001)
    {
        break;
    }
    bool isprime = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < numprime; i++)
    {
        if((counter % arrofprimes[i]) == 0)
        {
            isprime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isprime)
    {
        numprime++;
        arrofprimes[numprime - 1] = counter;
    }
    counter++;
}
cout << counter << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why not `while(numprime < 10001)` instead of leading with a conditional break? Even better, why not a constant to express the number of iterations?

Comment: The best thing for you to do is to step through with a debugger.

Comment: Time to debug it, then. Luckily for you, [Eric Lippert wrote an article about this very subject](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Why do `numprime++; arrofprimes[numprime - 1] = counter;` when you could have `arrofprimes[numprime] = counter; numprime++; `?

Comment: Aside: Given you 'prime' (excuse the pun) with 2 why not `counter+=2`. Even numbers will be kicked out pretty quickly but actually you don't need to test them or indeed try `% 2` on the candidates.

Answer (score 2):

You have incremented the counter *after* finding the 10001st prime, giving you an off-by-one error.